# How to tell IIS7 to redirect traffic to asp.net

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, url-rewriting

I have a url rewrite routine in `global.asax`, when the user types:

`http://example.com/products/category/electronics`

the server serves:

`http://example.com/products.aspx?category=45`

the problem is that IIS7 does not send this request to be handled by asp.net because the requested path has no folder in the directory structure.

How can I tell IIS to let this request be handled by asp.net without creating a directory for each product and category?

Comment: Why not just use MVC since it has this functionality built into it out of the box? Coaxing IIS7 to do this instead of going with what's already out there seems fruitless.

Comment: @joel - the OP is clearly committed to ASP.NET Forms, telling him/her to "just use MVC" is not constructive. IIS7's URL Rewriting module is the clear solution here.

Comment: @ Kev Ω - I"m not, otherwise I would have answered. I was asking if there is a reason it can't be used. I'd like to know that before I begin investigating alternative methods. I can see how my comment can be construed in that way, but it's not intended as such. I'm more interested in isolating the restrictions first.

Answer (score 2):

Technically you don't have IIS do this, you use URL Re-Writing to do it.  This is a normal feature of ASP.NET MVC.  However, it's possible in "classic" form-based asp.net as well.

There's an article about it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx

Listed in the article are a number of ways to accomplish this, as well as a detailed explanation of writing an httpModule.

As a matter of fact, the article shows how to do EXACTLY what you're asking.  Search on the page for "when a user visits /Products/Beverages.aspx" on the page and it'll take you right to the demonstration of how it works.  (Instructions are higher up in the article.)

Comment: the link was very useful, thanks. Maybe an httpmodule may be the best way for me. I'd have to play around with it since I've never written one.

Answer (score 2):

In a nutshell don't do this in your `Global.asax`. Use the IIS7 Url Rewriter instead:

> [Using the URL Rewrite Module](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-the-url-rewrite-module/)

You have one of two solutions -

1. Use a [URL Rewrite Map](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/469/using-rewrite-maps-in-url-rewrite-module/) and map every category name to a category ID:

   ```
   <rewrite>
     <rewriteMaps>
       <rewriteMap name="StaticRewrites">
         <add key="/products/category/electronics" value="/products.aspx?category=45" />
         <add key="/products/category/books" value="/products.aspx?category=46" />
         <add key="/products/category/dvds" value="/products.aspx?category=47" />
       </rewriteMap>
     </rewriteMaps>
     <rules>
       <rule name="Rewrite Rule 1 for StaticRewrites" stopProcessing="true">
         <match url=".*" />
         <conditions>
           <add input="{StaticRewrites:{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern="(.+)" />
         </conditions>
         <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="False"/>
       </rule>
     </rules>
   </rewrite>
   ```
2. Use a more "dynamic" rewrite:

   ```
   <rewrite>
     <rules>
       <rule name="RedirectUserFriendlyURL1" stopProcessing="true">
         <match url="^products\.aspx$" />
         <conditions>
           <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^POST$" negate="true" />
           <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^([^=&amp;]+)=([^=&amp;]+)$" />
         </conditions>
         <action type="Redirect" url="products/{C:1}/{C:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
       </rule>
       <rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL1" stopProcessing="true">
         <match url="^products/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$" />
         <conditions>
           <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
           <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
         </conditions>
         <action type="Rewrite" url="products.aspx?{R:1}={R:2}" />
       </rule>
     </rules>
   </rewrite>
   ```

   In the above case you'd need to change your `products.aspx` page to accept the category name, then in that page look up the actual integer ID of the category in the database.

Passing the rewrite responsibility to IIS7's URL Rewrite module (or any other rewriter such as Iconics IIRF or HeliconTech's ISAPI Rewrite) means that you can change these rules separately rather than burning them into your code. Burning these rules into your code means you have to redeploy every time you make a change.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. ASP.NET MVC is not out of the question, I simply haven't used it yet, so I don't feel capable of making a change like that of an existing project (unless you say is super easy). I'll try IIS7's Url Rewrite. But I would rather handle that in code than in a config file since a lookup table can be done through a database not needing me to change the code, but rather update the database. Thanks again.